# AsyncStorage display information

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, asyncstorage

I would like to display some information which is stored in the AsyncStorage function.
It works well, but when I add an item inside this list, I need to restart my application to see the modifications.
I think I have to use a useEffect hook but I tried a lot of things and didn't find the solution.
If someone could just explain me where is the problem with my code. Thanks you in advance I continue my research by my side.

I set my informations in the AsyncStorage like this:

```
 AsyncStorage.setItem(
        `listeElements:${data["fk_produit_id"]}`,
        JSON.stringify(data["fk_produit_id"])
      );
```

And there is my code to put the information in a useState array:

```
const getProduct = async (id) => {
    if (id) {
      dispatch(authAction.Favorite(id))
        .then((response) => {
          const newArray = response.array;

          setInformations(newArray);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
        });
    } else {
      const keys = await AsyncStorage.getAllKeys();
      let tempInformations = [...informations];
      if (keys) {
        for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
          const key = keys[i];
          if (key.startsWith("listeElements")) {
            const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);
            await fetch(
              `http://ip_adress/api/users/favorite?value=${value}`,
              {
                method: "GET",
                headers: {
                  "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
              }
            )
              .then((response) =>
                response.json().then((responseJson) => {
                  const newArray = responseJson.array;
                  tempInformations = [...tempInformations, ...newArray];
                })
              )
              .catch((e) => console.log(e));
          }
        }
        setInformations(tempInformations);
      }
    }
  };

useEffect(() => {
    getProduct(decoded._id);
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      setRefreshTime(Date.now());
    }, 3000);
    return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
  }, [decoded]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by using `useIsFocused` of `@react-navigation/native`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

AsyncStorage.setItem don‘t trigger rerender, probably you have to trigger a rerender manually

```
const forceUpdate = React.useCallback(() => updateState({}), []);
forceUpdate()

…

await AsyncStorage.setItem(
        `listeElements:${data["fk_produit_id"]}`,
        JSON.stringify(data["fk_produit_id"])
);

forceUpdate()
…
```

Comment: thanks you for your response, I tried your modifications but nothing change